# Spring Config Not Picking Up Env Variable

Tags: spring, environment-variables

I have an env variable $MONGODB_URI

```
echo $MONGODB_URI
mongodb://localhost:27017
```

My application.properties

```
mongoUri=${MONGODB_URI}
```

My Config.java

```
@Configuration

public class Config {

@Value("${mongoUri}")
private String mongoUri;
```

..

}

When I try to start up the app in IntelliJ Idea, I get

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'MONGODB_URI' in value "${MONGODB_URI}"
```

The app starts up fine with

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

How can I properly configure IntelliJ to read from the environment? I'll need to swap out the db url depending on if it's prod, local, etc.

Comment: how are you running app via terminal or ide?

Comment: I am running it via the IDE

Comment: which ide please specify.

Comment: IntelliJ Idea from Jetbrains

Answer (score 0):

You need to run to your application with environment configuration as shown below in image:

[image]

sample code to verify

```java
@RestController
public class StatusController {

    private final Environment environment;

    public StatusController(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
    @GetMapping("/env")
    public String envValue() {
        return environment.getProperty("MONGODB_URI");
    }
}
```